# hdfs Journal node giving alerts "fsync latency concerning"

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I am getting these alerts from cloudera manager. The health test result for JOURNAL_NODE_FSYNC_LATENCY has become concerning: The 99th percentile fsync latency over the previous minute is 2.3 second(s). Warning threshold: 1 second(s).

I checked in cloudera documentation it shows 1sec is warning and 3sec is critical. What is the cause for this problem and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> The cause; JournalNode Fsync Latency "JOURNAL_NODE_FSYNC_LATENCY"

This is a JournalNode health test that checks the JournalNode's fsync latency. This test returns "Bad" health if the 99th percentile fsync latency over the previous minute is above a configured threshold value. Poor fsync performance may indicate a bad or overloaded disk (ie JournalNode share the same disk with NameNode and DataNode.) and will negatively impact the performance of HDFS metadata operations performed by the NameNode.

> How to solve this;
>   On the affected node monitor your disk using iostat; or move the JournalNode contents onto a seperate disk.

Comment: Michalis thanks for your reply. I have lot of disk space on the nodes and I am getting alerts from 2 journal nodes out of three journal nodes. have almost 62% of disk space available on both the nodes. Can you be more specific in the answer.